# Loaded png into GIMP looks wierd

Tags: gimp, png

(Not an experienced designer / GIMP user)

When loading the Kubernetes png logo into GIMP, I get a weird result. How can I solve this?

Logo file: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/logo/logo_with_border.png

Result:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have two layers, and the canvas is likely set to fit the initial layer (600x300, while the K8S image you have is 3600x3500) (what you see is the center of the K8S logo). Try `Image>Fit canvas to layers` or scale down the K8S logo layer.

Comment: "what you see is the center of the K8S logo" - I thought this heptagon is the outline of the logo and the helm inside is missing... Stupid question on my side. Thanks!